# string.Compare Not returning 0 why?

Tags: c#, string-comparison

i am trying to compare text of radiobutton with the text of label here is the code

`radiobutton4.Text = 'a'` and `label2.Text = 'a'`

but `string.Compare(label2.Text,radiobutton4.Text) != 0` why ?

Comment: Trailing spaces etc...?

Comment: Are you sure there is no any non-printable character? Check `Length` property.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem... bearing in mind that you really don't need a UI for this at all, as you're just comparing strings. I strongly suspect that the problem is within the strings themselves, so determining the *exact* content is the most important part of diagnosing the issue for now.

Comment: When comparing strings, you should call the Compare(String, String, StringComparison) method, which requires that you explicitly specify the type of string comparison that the method uses. For more information, see Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework.[msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/84787k22)

Comment: you can try Trim() and ToUpper()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: nathing happening dataset is same datasource is same i cant understand whats the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
string.Compare(label2.Text.Trim(),radiobutton4.Text.Trim())
```